# Convert function into a completable with custom Exceptions

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have a vertx service for all message-broker related operations. For e.g. an exchange creation function looks like this

```
@Override
    public BrokerService createExchange(String exchange, 
    Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> resultHandler) {
        try {
            getAdminChannel(exchange).exchangeDeclare(exchange, "topic", true);
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(e.getCause()));
        }
        return this;
    }
```

I am in the process of converting my entire codebase into rxjava and I would like to convert functions like these into completables. Something like:

```
try {
    getAdminChannel(exchange).exchangeDeclare(exchange, "topic", true);
    Completable.complete();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Completable.error(new BrokerErrorThrowable("Exchange creation failed"));
}
```

Furthermore, I would also like to be able to throw custom errors like `Completable.error(new BrokerErrorThrowable("Exchange creation failed"))` when things go wrong. This is so that I'll be able to catch these errors and respond with appropriate HTTP responses.

I saw that `Completable.fromCallable()` is one way to do it, but I haven't found a way to throw these custom exceptions. How do I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. All I had to do was this:

```
@Override
  public BrokerService createExchange(String exchange, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler) {
    Completable.fromCallable(
            () -> {
              try {
                getAdminChannel(exchange).exchangeDeclare(exchange, "topic", true);
                return Completable.complete();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                return Completable.error(new InternalErrorThrowable("Create exchange failed"));
              }
            })
        .subscribe(CompletableHelper.toObserver(resultHandler));

    return this;
  }
```